# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation not resizing view in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

When I use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation on a view it does not resize the view. It cuts part of the view out. It works just fine on iOS 5.1, but for some reason it does not work on iOS 6.

Could someone please help explain what I am doing wrong/not taking into consideration that was added in iOS 6?

Here is the code I am using:

```
zoomStepper.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(270.0/180*M_PI);
```

While the view rotates as expected in iOS 5, in iOS 6 it does not.
The views have the same bounds and frame after rotation in both iOS 5 and iOS 6. I am wondering how I can get the iOS 5 behavior for rotate in iOS 6.

iOS 5: [image: iOS 5 screenshot]

iOS 6: [image: iOS 6 screenshot]

Comment: A rotation transform does not resize a view. It rotates the view. A scale transform does resize the view. What are you expecting? If the view rotates, your code is working.

Comment: I guess then what I am asking is if their is a way to resize the view after rotation so that the view fits.

Comment: I don't know because I don't know what you want to do or what is happening. You just showed one line of code and that line of code, as far as anyone can tell from here, is working perfectly. You have not stated the problem. (Idea: howzabout posting a screenshot and explaining what you don't like about what's happening?)

Comment: Are you using exactly the same code and xibs/storyboards on iOS 5 and iOS 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. If you create a new View and apply the rotation to that view and then add the view you wish to rotate as a subview it will rotate it for you and it works on both iOS 5 and iOS 6:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 94, 27)]; 
[myView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(270.0/180*M_PI)]; 
[self.view addSubview:myView]; 
[myView addSubview:zoomStepper];
```